# Export SQL data by field

Tags: sql

I have an SQL database and I want to export the data based on criteria for one field.  For example,

Table fields:
Number
Date
Header
Notes

The Number field contains duplicate entries but all the other information is different for each entry.  I need to export all the Date, Header, and Notes data for each Number field where the Number = xxxxx (the number I want to export).

I'm new to SQL and queries so appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
select Date, Header,Notes
from table
where number = xxxxx


SELECT                 -- keyword to retrieve data
   date, header, notes -- list of columns I want to retrieve
FROM table             -- name of table to get data from
WHERE                  -- Restrictions to limit what data rows to bring back
```

This should get your started, there is much, much more you can do with the SELECT statement and its options